# MySQL: Is it absolutely normal to have 9 tables with InnoDB engine, but decide to keep 1 table with MYISAM one?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, myisam

I switched all, but one tables to InnoDB engine from MyISAM. 
What about the last logs table? You INSERT in there but never SELECT from there (as far as I know today, MyISAM is better, than InnoDB in this case).

Should I switch it to InnoDB engine as well as it's the last unswitched table? Or, keeping 1 table among many tables with a different engine is absolutely normal?

Comment: What does this ";ast logs" table store exactly?

Comment: it stores id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, varchar(15)NULL, timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL, varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL.PRIMARY KEY (`id`). ENGINE=InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal to keep a few tables in MyISAM engine, especially for two cases:

- Full Text search
- Spatial indexes (meaning: If you want to search for Latitudes/Longitudes and other spatial queries, fast)

Comment: What about my case?  Thank you.

Comment: Oh, you edited from ***"Lat Logs"*** to ***"last logs"***. I'll answer later, in a hurry now.

Comment: I'm still waiting for your reply... Thank you.